# Button select's group of radio buttons by class name

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that is selecting a group of radio buttons. Right now the javascript select the radio buttons by getting the element by ID. I wanted to see if there would be a way to do this with class name rather than ID? Any help here would be greatly appreciated. You can see how my code is behaving in the example given, I just would prefer to use class name over the ID.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="check()">Select All Option 1</button>
<button onclick="uncheck()">Un-Select Option 1</button>

<table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Count</th>
          <th scope="col">Type 1</th>
          <th scope="col">Type 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">0</th>
          <td>

            <!-- Group of default radios - option 1 -->
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input allOption1" id="option1Id1" name="group1">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1Id1">Option 1</label>
          </div>

          </td>
          <td>

              <!--  Group of default radios - option 2 -->
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="option1Id2" name="group1" >
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1Id2">Option 2</label>
              </div>
          </td>
          
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>

              <!-- Group of default radios - option 1 -->
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input allOption1" id="option2Id1" name="group2">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="option2Id1">Option 1</label>
              </div>

          </td>
          <td>

              <!--  Group of default radios - option 2 -->
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="option2Id2" name="group2" >
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="option2Id2">Option 2</label>
              </div>


          </td>
          
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>

          
          
          
<script>
function check() {
document.getElementById("option1Id1").checked = true; 
document.getElementById("option2Id1").checked = true;
/* document.getElementsByClassName('allOption1').checked = true;  */
}



function uncheck() {
  document.getElementById("option1Id1").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("option2Id1").checked = true; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get element's by class names using one of at least two methods.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
```

or

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".classname"); // Note the "." as this method uses CSS selectors
```

You can then loop through either of these variables, which by the way are `NodeList`s not JS `Array`s.

```
for(var e = 0; e < elements.length; e++) {
  // do something with elements[e]
}
```

Have a look at the docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).